# How to use loggingEvent class with log4j 2.12.1

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have to migrate log4j-1.2.17 to log4j-2.12.1 in java project
In 2.12 version loggingEvent class not implement(getthreadname, loggername,logmessage) methods, but I have to use those methods for my project. Is there any similar class to call those methods

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to follow the migration path: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html

Maybe you could add the old class names to your methods which you are missing in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Many people who used Log4j 1.2 overrode a lot of its functionality because it was lacking features they needed. Log4j 2 is a complete rearchitecture and rewrite. It is more flexible and can do many of the things you may have been customizing out of the box. Before going down the path of just blatantly trying to convert your Log4j 1 adaptations to Log4j 2, first determine what the goals of those customizations are and then determine the best approach to implement them in Log4j 2. If you have questions on how to implement some specific feature either ask here on Stackoverflow or on one of the Apache Logging Services mailing lists. Information on the mailing lists can be found at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/mail-lists.html